# how to add the particular key values in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

```
Array
(
    [csv_data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => CAM
                    [1] => Partner
                    [2] => Division
                    [3] => Domain
                    [4] => Year
                    [5] => Quarter
                    [6] => Tactic
                    [7] => Impressions
                    [8] => Responders

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => CAM
                    [1] => Acme and Brick
                    [2] => Belgium
                    [3] => www.partnerA.com
                    [4] => 2016
                    [5] => Q2
                    [6] => Single Email Campaign
                    [7] => 8000
                    [8] => 6000

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => Acme and Brick
                    [2] => Belgium
                    [3] => www.partnerA.com
                    [4] => 2016
                    [5] => Q2
                    [6] => Multi-Touch Email Campaign
                    [7] => 350
                    [8] => 200

                )



            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => TestR
                    [1] => Partner R2
                    [2] => India
                    [3] => www.partnerA.com
                    [4] => 2016
                    [5] => Q1
                    [6] => Single Email Campaign
                    [7] => 9000
                    [8] => 4000

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => Partner R2
                    [2] => India
                    [3] => www.partnerA.com
                    [4] => 2016
                    [5] => Q2
                    [6] => Linkedin(Groups)
                    [7] => 350
                    [8] => 200

                )

        )

)
```

Hello, i am new in PHP.
i just want that in this array i want to add the particular array key values and identify that it sholud be has the same partner and divison after identify the values of all particular should be add in new array.

ANSWER should be like this:

```
    Array
(
    [csv_data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => CAM
                    [1] => Partner
                    [2] => Division
                    [3] => Domain
                    [4] => Year
                    [5] => Quarter
                    [6] => Tactic
                    [7] => Impressions
                    [8] => Responders

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => CAM
                    [1] => Acme and Brick
                    [2] => Belgium
                    [3] => www.partnerA.com
                    [4] => 2016
                    [5] => Q2
                    [6] => Single Email Campaign
                    [7] => 8350
                    [8] => 6200

                )




            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => TestR
                    [1] => Partner R2
                    [2] => India
                    [3] => www.partnerA.com
                    [4] => 2016
                    [5] => Q1
                    [6] => Single Email Campaign
                    [7] => 9350
                    [8] => 4200

                )



        )

)
```

Comment: can you please explain little more, what result do you expecting from that array ???

Comment: It's not very clear to me what the result has to be.

Comment: All I know is one was removed... {index: 2}

Comment: ^ and 4. Those with empty 0 index

Comment: @ManjeetBarnala see the array above on index 1 the value 'Acme and Brick' should be match with the index 2 key 1 .if they both match then the key 7 of index 1 and index 2 should be added and all the values should be come in one array().

Comment: @JamesLalor i update it

Comment: okay i understand, now tell me you want only 7th key only or whole index in new array ??  @Sunnyraturi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, this will definitely work for you..

```
$removeKeys = array();                  
foreach($data['csv_data'] as $key => $val)///loop through array..
{
    foreach($data['csv_data'] as $k => $v)
    {
        if($val[1] == $v[1] && $key != $k)////check if key 1 matches 
        {
            if(!in_array($key,$removeKeys)) ////check if item is already added or not
            {
                $removeKeys[] = $k; ///push into removed keys because this is added into matched item 
                $data['csv_data'][$key][7]+=$data['csv_data'][$k][7];
                $data['csv_data'][$key][8]+=$data['csv_data'][$k][8];
            }
        }
    }
}
foreach($removeKeys as $rk) 
{
   unset($data['csv_data'][$rk]); ////remove all the keys in removeKeys
}
print_r($data['csv_data']);///your desired output...
```

This will give you :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => CAM
            [1] => Partner
            [2] => Division
            [3] => Domain
            [4] => Year
            [5] => Quarter
            [6] => Tactic
            [7] => Impressions
            [8] => Responders
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => CAM
            [1] => Acme and Brick
            [2] => Belgium
            [3] => www.partnerA.com
            [4] => 2016
            [5] => Q2
            [6] => Single Email Campaign
            [7] => 8350
            [8] => 6200
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => TestR
            [1] => Partner R2
            [2] => India
            [3] => www.partnerA.com
            [4] => 2016
            [5] => Q1
            [6] => Single Email Campaign
            [7] => 9350
            [8] => 4200
        )

)
```

***LIVE EXAMPLE : [CLICK HERE](https://eval.in/584628)***